# Adding two values to ajax autocomplete function in Asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have search textbox and i whould like to implement autocomplete checking in it. When you type one letter autocomplete need to give you all the names with that letter. 
I found tutorial with that but my problem is what I whould like implement two radio buttons and if first one is checked it will give you only suggestion for Clients, and if second one is checked it will give you only suggestion for companies.

I thried with this code in Web service .asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public class Autocomplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]

    public List<string> GetClientNames(string searchTerm,string rbtnValue)
    {
        List<string> clientNames = new List<string>();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RheosConnString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            if (rbtnValue == "radio0")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetClientNames", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@term", searchTerm);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                        clientNames.Add(sdr["ime"].ToString());

                }
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCompanyNames", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@term", searchTerm);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {

                        clientNames.Add(sdr["naziv"].ToString());

                }
            }

        }
        return clientNames;
    }

}
```

My Javascript looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var value = $("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Autocomplete.asmx/GetStudentNames",
                        data: {searchTerm: request.term, rbtnValue:value},
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('Postoji problem s dohvaćanjem zahtjeva');
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 0
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Do I need implement something else for radiobuttons. My value is radio0 and radio1.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: What's weird is, you want to get clients or companies, but your web service method in the javascript is `GetStudentNames`. Among other things.

Comment: I didnt get any error, just my autocomplete is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

In you service the method name is `GetClientNames` but in your ajax call you are calling to method `GetStudentNames`. Most probably this could be the issue. If this is not the issue kindly share your error so I would be able to help you out.

Comment: I change it and no help. Is there possibility that browser has autoinput and that conflicts with my. Maybe turn autocomplete off whould that help